# Google Analytics V3.03 not sending back data

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I have run the example version supplied by Google and that works and I have used that to make the tracking in my app (the documentation on their site references the previous version so is pretty much useless) but I cannot get the tracking to send.

It either says No pending hits or says that it has sent but it doesn't appear in my analytics and yet the Google one does and the code is identical.

In the app delegate there is

```
NSDictionary *appDefaults = @{kAllowTracking: @(YES)};
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:appDefaults];
// User must be able to opt out of tracking
[GAI sharedInstance].optOut =
![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kAllowTracking];
// Initialize Google Analytics with a 120-second dispatch interval. There is a
// tradeoff between battery usage and timely dispatch.
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
self.tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithName:@"My app."
                                          trackingId:@"UA-XXXXXXXX-X"];
```

Which is identical to Googles code and then in the view I want to send back is

```
self.screenName = @"WORK";
```

which again is the same as what they use. The correct files are imported and everything as far as I can tell is identical (obviously not as it isn't working)

This is driving my nuts, any help is greatly appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ok after spending too much time on this I have figured out why it wasn't working.
Turns out you have to have the [super xyz] method for viewdidload and viewdidappear
Adding these two super's in (I was missing the [super viewdidappear] made it work)

Edit
You may need it in viewWillAppear as well but have not tested this

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm in the exact same boat, can't seem to get the events to show up in the realtime view for GA, added super calls for `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear`. I've set logging to verbose and it seems to show that events were uploaded successfully `2014-02-17 11:08:04.481 XXXXX[1998:70b] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.03a -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:response:data:error:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:157): Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status 200`

Comment: Try adding a super call in `viewWillAppear` ?
I did get it working and the super calls were the only thing I changed between it not working and it working
Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah thanks, I did have a super call in `viewWillAppear`. I figured out what the issue was though, turns out you can't use the same GA  property id for a web site and an app, my app loads some online content and i thought it would be good to get a single view of all interaction, but that doesn't work. [Reference](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2587087).